# Распарсить запрос в JSON

Tags: javascript, json, парсер

Имеются запросы вида:

```
str and (str or str)
str and str or str
str and not str
str and str {str {str}}
...etc
```

Нужно распарсить строки в JSON объект. Например:

```
str and (str or str) => 
{and: [
  str,
  {
    or: [
     str,
     str
    ]
  }
]}

str and str {str {str}} => 
{and: [
  str,
  {
     str: {
       str: {
         str
       }
    }
  }
]}
```

Подскажите, какой наилучший способ выбрать для этого? На данный момент разделяю строку на элементы по операторам `and,or и тд.`, получаю массив элементов и работаю с каждым, запоминая оператор. Выбираю, по какому оператору сплитить, по приоритету, гди у `И` самый высокий приоритет, затем `ИЛИ` и тд. Сплитила с учетом скобок - то есть все, что в скобках, становилось отдельным элементом, и затем сплитилось вновь. Чем не нравится способ - шаг влево или вправо - что-то да отвалится.

Comment: Вы лучше приведите в пример код, который у вас есть.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko  он довольно объемный, а мне нужен только алгоритм действий

Comment: Хорошо, ждите человека, который весь объемный новый код напишет для вас с нуля. Только не дождетесь, скорее всего :)

Comment: Мне не нужен код, мне нуден алгоритм. Я предоставила свой алгоритм действий, прошу участников лишь предложить возможный словесный вариант решения) За меня ничего писать не нужно

Comment: Извините, конечно, но у вас не описание алгоритма. Точнее, оно настолько общее, что не несет практической пользы. По нему невозможно написать работающий код. Точно так же, услышав от нас словесное описание алгоритма, вы не сможете написать на нем код. Для описания алгоритмов использует: формальный язык, блок-схемы, псевдокод. Ну или непосредственно сам код.